# Messagedlg in Delphi xe7 android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I m just trying to execute a sample given during the installation of Delphi xe7, the MessageAlerts on android platform, unfortunately it does not working, it gives the following error message:

> Blocking Dialogs not implemented in this platform

```
procedure TMessageAlertsForm.btnMultiButtonAlertClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { Show a multiple-button alert that triggers different code blocks according to
    your input }
  case MessageDlg('Choose a button:', System.UITypes.TMsgDlgType.mtInformation,
    [
      System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes,
      System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo,
      System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbCancel
    ], 0) of
    { Detect which button was pushed and show a different message }
    mrYES:
      ShowMessage('You chose Yes');
    mrNo:
      ShowMessage('You chose No');
    mrCancel:
      ShowMessage('You chose Cancel');
  end;
end;
```

Any idea How to solve it?

Comment: You should always **add** the generic [tag:delphi] tag to your delphi related questions to have the correct syntax highlighter and more attention on your question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is explained in the XE7 release notes:

[Dialog Box Methods Support Anonymous Methods to Handle Their Closing](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What's_New_in_Delphi_and_C++Builder_XE7#Dialog_Box_Methods_Support_Anonymous_Methods_to_Handle_Their_Closing)

> In XE6, calls to dialog box methods (InputBox, InputQuery, MessageDlg, ShowMessage) were always blocking. Any code after a call to one of these methods is not executed until the dialog box closes. **Android does not allow blocking dialog boxes, so you could not use these methods on Android.**
>
> On XE7, InputBox, InputQuery, and MessageDlg support a **new optional parameter, *ACloseDialogProc*. Calls that include this new parameter work on all platforms, including Android. This new optional parameter allows you to provide an anonymous method that is called when the dialog box closes.** When you call these methods using this new parameter, your call is blocking in desktop platforms and non-blocking in mobile platforms. If you need to execute code after your dialog box closes, use this new parameter to ensure that your application works as expected on all supported platforms.
>
> ...
>
> ShowMessage also gained support for Android in XE7, and calls to ShowMessage are blocking on desktop platforms and non-blocking on mobile platforms. However, ShowMessage does not provide any new parameter to handle its closing. **If you need to execute code after the dialog box that ShowMessage shows closes, use MessageDlg instead of ShowMessage.**

For example:

```
procedure TMessageAlertsForm.btnMultiButtonAlertClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MessageDlg('Choose a button:', System.UITypes.TMsgDlgType.mtInformation,
    [
      System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes,
      System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo,
      System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbCancel
    ], 0,
    procedure(const AResult: System.UITypes.TModalResult)
    begin
      case AResult of
        mrYES:
          ShowMessage('You chose Yes');
        mrNo:
          ShowMessage('You chose No');
        mrCancel:
          ShowMessage('You chose Cancel');
      end;
    end);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Is there anyway we can replace `System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes` for a custom String? This is a good solution but fails when it comes about dealing with non-english apps.

Comment: @Holmes: The `mb*` and `mr*` values are all constant ID numbers, not strings.  There is nothing in this code that is dependent on string localizations, so it should work as-is on all platforms and configurations equally.

Comment: Then what would you do if you need to set "Yes" and "No" into your local language? *i.e. Deustch "Ya" - "Nein".* Isn't there anything we could do about that?

Comment: @Holmes: This is what resource strings are meant for. Change the code to pass custom `resourcestring` values to `ShowMessage()`, and then you can localize the `resourcestring` values as needed. That has nothing to do with the `MessageDlg` dialog itself (which already uses localized resource strings internally for its UI).

Comment: @RemyLebeau how can this be modal on android and dont close until a button click?! now in android if i click other place on screen dialog disappear !!

Comment: @peimanF. It is not modal at all. It is asynchronous, simply showing a Form window normally and then calling the anonymous procedure when the window is closed.