# Blocking dialogs not implemented on this platform - Delphi Firemonkey Android

Tags: android, delphi, popup, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I needed to use Firemonkey **MessageDlg** and **InputBox** a lot. In Windows everything is fine but when I compile it for Android, I got a message **blocking dialogs not implemented on this platform**.

```
interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, ..., FMX.Dialogs, ...;

...
...
...



Procedure TformName.buttonCloseIssueClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    Val:String;
begin

Val := FMX.Dialogs.InputBox('Close Issue','Reason:','');

if Val <> '' then
begin
 //.. my codes
else
 ShowMessage('Something went wrong');
 Exit;
end;

 //.. other codes
end;
```

How to make **popup input**, **message box** and **confirmation** in Android platform?

Edit: My version is Delphi XE8 Professional with Mobile Add-On Pack

Comment: did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376120/messagedlg-in-delphi-xe7-android)

Comment: I couldn't do this with InputBox. Is there any differences from MessageDlg? This is not helpful for InputBox usage.

Comment: @AbdullahIlgaz I have the same problem and need blocking dialogs. I have written a small but dirty solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39142888/1854856 It does work with InputQuery too, but I use the new unified dialog API of version 10.1 Berlin. However it should work the same with XE8, since XE8 introduced the support for the anonymous callback function (afaik) for dialogs. So instead of `TDialogService.MessageDialog(...)` you can keep using your `FMX.Dialogs.InputBox(...)`. I hope it helps you a little bit.